# How to convert a table to multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have tons of spreadsheets that are formatted like this first table (but with a lot more records and different number of records). I need to make it take all the right information but format it like the second table for importing into Access. Can this be done? Thanks.

..........part 1    part 2  part 3  part 4
Test 1..5
Test 2.............x.........5
Test 3..2.........x..................x
Test 4.......................x.........x
Test 5..x..............................2

Test 1  Part 1  5
Test 2  part 2  x
Test 2  part 3  5
Test 3  part 1  2
Test 3  part 2  x
Test 3  part 4  x
Test 4  part 3  x
Test 4  part 4  x
Test 5  part 1  x
Test 5  part 4  2

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it.  You could also use For Each loops for the Ranges.

```
Dim workingRange1 As Range, workingRange2 As Range

Set workingRange1 = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
Set workingRange2 = Range("PutStuffHere")


For i = 0 to workingRange1.Rows.Count - 2
  For j = 0 to workingRange1.Columns.Count - 2
    If Not IsEmpty(workingRange1.Cells(i+1, j+1))
      workingRange2.Offset(0, 0) = workingRange1.Cells(i+1, 1)
      workingRange2.Offset(0, 1) = workingRange1.Cells(1, j+1)
      workingRange2.Offset(0, 2) = workingRange1.Cells(i+1, j+1)
    End If
    Set workingRange2 = workingRange2.Offset(1,0)
  Next j
Next i
```